# CSS - Drop Down Menu (Fixed Width)

Tags: css

Could you please take a look at the harvard medical school website here
http://hms.harvard.edu/

The last item of the navigation drop down menu has the sub menu not being displayed out of its fixed div. That is: the sub menu position of the last item is adjusted so that it won't float out.

How to do it in pure css?

Hope you understand what I am talking about. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On that particular website it's done by manual positioning of the last element.

All the other submenus have `{ position: absolute; left: 0; }` but the very last one `left: -91px`. You can attach a class to the last menu item (or use `:last-child` but that won't work in older IE-s) and move it to the left to fit into the main content box.

Comment: Thank you Zonltan I got that!